# Multithreading this sample code:

Tags: android

So here's some code on http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/16a2216b39513674 in which the poster writes that he's shortened ideas into a single threaded app.  A respondent below his post says, essentially, that's great, nice work, but there are benefits to multithreading so things don't interfere with other stuff on your handset.

My question is:  Evidently, the original poster reduced, distilled ideas from multithreaded examples he saw in order to make them easier to read, posted them, cool.  But what would a multithreaded version of the below code look like?

Would Runnable be on a separate thread?  Or the whole callback?  Or not those but something else?  Anything else?

Would it be even better if it were run as a service, and then a Runnable thread spawned from the service?  Is a service considered a separate thread from the UI?

As you can tell this question is about the basics of multithreading for Android.  Thanks for any info.

```
public class Something extends Activity { 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saved) { 
      super.onResume(); 
      final EGL10 egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL(); 
      final EGLDisplay eglDisplay = egl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY); 
      int[] version = new int[2]; 
      egl.eglInitialize(eglDisplay, version); 

      int[] configSpec = { 
          // EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 8, 
          EGL10.EGL_NONE 
      }; 

      final EGLConfig[] config = new EGLConfig[1]; 
      int num_configs[] = new int[1]; 
      egl.eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, configSpec, config, 1, num_configs); 
      final EGLContext eglContext = egl.eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, config[0], EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, null); 

      // Setting up layouts and views 
      SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this); 
      setContentView(view); 

      SurfaceHolder holder = view.getHolder(); 
      holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_GPU); 
      final GL10 gl = (GL10) eglContext.getGL(); 
      final Handler handler = new Handler(); 

      holder.addCallback(new Callback() {
        private EGLSurface surface; 
        private Runnable painter; 

        @Override 
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) { 
          // initialize GL projection and other stuff 
          // gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); 
          // gl.glFrustumf(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar); 
          // ... 
          painter = new Runnable() { 
            @Override 
            public void run() { 
              drawFrame(gl); 
              egl.eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, surface); 
              handler.post(this); 
            } 
          }; 
          handler.post(painter); 
        } 
        @Override 
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
          surface = egl.eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, config[0], holder, null); 
          egl.eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, surface, surface, eglContext); 
        } 
        @Override 
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
          handler.removeCallbacks(painter); 
        } 
      });
    } 

    private void drawFrame(GL10 gl) { 
      // Frame drawing... 
      long t = System.currentTimeMillis() % 10000; 
      gl.glClearColor(t / (float) 10000, t / (float) 10000 ,1 , 1); 
      gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in a great article from Google Android Team titled [Painless threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

As with my own words, AsyncTask is an intelligent Thread that has two methods that run on UI thread, so you can update your UI in those methods.

Comment: idd AsyncTask is a life saver.check it out